# gcc compilation with linker - differences

Tags: c, gcc, linker

This will compile `main.c` and link created `.o` file statically with with `abc` library and dynamically with `xyz`

```
gcc main.c -Wl,-Bstatic -labc -Wl,-Bdynamic -lxyz -o main
```

But I am not sure about some other combinations:

1. This will compile `main.c` to `main` - but what `-lm` will do in this case?

   `gcc main.c -o main -lm`
2. Here we use `-Wl` which let us provide some options to linker: `-Bstatic, -lm` say that it should be linked statically with `m` library (libm) - but what `-Wl,-Bdynamic` is doing here? And with which library it is related?
   gcc main.c -o main -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic

   `gcc main.c -o main -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic`
3. What `-static` flag is doing here? Why it is before `main.c`?

   `gcc -static main.c -o main -lm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `-lm` will link in `libm`. By default gcc will search for the shared library first. If the shared version is not found it will then search for the static version.
2. The trailing `-Wl,-Bdynamic` is to ensure that the shared version of standard libraries (ie, `libc`) are used.
3. `-static` prevents linking with shared libraries. It can be placed anywhere on the command line and will have the same effect. This is different to `-Wl,-Bstatic` in that `-static` applies to linking of all libraries whereas `-Wl,-Bstatic` only applies to libraries after it in the command line. Please note that `-static` is also different to `-Wl,-static`. The former is a gcc driver option and prevents all dynamic linking. The latter is an ld option and is an alias for `-Wl,-Bstatic`.